# modx revo adding fields in user module

Tags: modx

I am new to modx revo and trying to add extra fields in user creation from backend. Which file should i check out for customization. I added the custom field in backend with this code on `modx.panel.user.js` file.

```
{
    id: 'modx-user-companyname'
    ,name: 'company_name'
    ,fieldLabel: _('company_name')
    ,xtype: 'textfield'
    ,anchor: '100%'
    ,maxLength: 255
}
```

I created custom column named `company_name` in database table `modx_users` but I don't know how to save it on database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the core code of modx is considered a bad idea.

Really you have two options if you want to add extra properties to users...

Firstly you could take advantage of `modUser` `extended` field which allows you to store extra  properties for the user and are stored as JSON. This is available in the default ui in the manager.

See [Understanding MODX Extended User Fields and JSON](http://bobsguides.com/blog.html/2013/11/03/understanding-modx-extended-fields-and-json/)

Secondly, you could extend `modUser`. This would give you full control over the user model and could then add additional related entities. From then, you might be able to alter the user form in the manager with form customisation or write a plugin to alter view.

See [Extending modUser](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/extending-moduser)